# ¿Cómo puedo añadir mi Bearer token y authorization en éste método?

Tags: java, spring-boot, test, tokens

```
@Test
void testGetMonedaPorId() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
    String response = mockMvc.perform(get("http://localhost:8080/CashLetterAPI/rest/moneda/findById" +"/{id}",1))
            .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.nombre", is("euro")))
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
 
    logger.info("response: " + response);
```

El tema es que estoy testeando un método , pero me da un error de 401 , es decir que no estoy autorizado , lo cuál es lógico porque necesito poner la cabecera con "authorization" y el Bearer token. ¿Cómo podría ponerlo en éste código? ¿Cuál sería la mejor manera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que añadir el header a tu petición.

Se puede hacer directamente de esta forma:

```java
@Test
void testGetMonedaPorId() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
    String response = mockMvc.perform(
         get("http://localhost:8080/CashLetterAPI/rest/moneda/findById" +"/{id}",1))
            .header("myKey", "myValue")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.nombre", is("euro")))
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
 
    logger.info("response: " + response);
}
```

O se puede crear mediante [HttpHeaders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpHeaders.html), el cual es conveniente cuando se tienen varios Headers que se estarán reusando.

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Your header");

@Test
void testGetMonedaPorId() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
    String response = mockMvc.perform(
         get("http://localhost:8080/CashLetterAPI/rest/moneda/findById" +"/{id}",1))
            .header(headers)
            .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.nombre", is("euro")))
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
 
    logger.info("response: " + response);
}
```